# How to pass an array using $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I know there are some similar questions but none of them solves my issue.

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post">
   Import data: <textarea type="text" name="import"></textarea>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then I get data from the "import" field:

```
$current = my_data();
$import = $_POST['import'];
$merge = array_merge($current,$import);
```

The problem is, even if I paste:

```
array('foo' => 'bar')
```

I get:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in
>   (address)
>   on line (line)

I can't change the HTML markup and I have to paste arrays there. Any ideas how to fix it? I've been reading about serialize() but not sure if there's anything to serialize is array() is not array() for PHP. Why is that? Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

$current hold an array of options for my theme.
$merge is supposed to hold the same keys with different values (around 30-50 of them, not multidimensional but might be in the future), but of course users might add new ones so in order to ignore them I'm actually using:

```
$imported_options = array_merge($current_options , array_intersect_key($_POST["import"], $current_options ));
```

(simplified this one as it's just an example)

So after all I want to load an array from the form and update the other array with it.

Comment: Why not use `array_push`?

Comment: or serialize it in JSON

Comment: I have some settings in $current and I need to update them, not to add new ones.

Comment: `$import` isn't an array you need to use `array_push` as @Rogue said. You could say `$merge = array_merge($current,$_POST);`

Comment: An array is a structure in PHP whereas what you are sending (even when you use the array syntax) is a simple string. What you need to do is send your string in a format that you can convert to an array in PHP. You could for example send it as JSON and use [json_decode](http://us2.php.net/json_decode).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: What do you want `$merge` to look like in the end?  Would something as simple as `$current['import'] = $_POST['import'];` work?

Comment: Would you please be so kind to emphasize on what data your actually trying to extract? ( What does $import actually contain? ). I'd reckon whatever format you are trying to import is not an array indeed as the error specifies, and you would have to convert it first? What do you mean by "even if I paste"?

Comment: That call to `array_intersect_key` seems superfluous.

Comment: What makes you think so? I've found this snippet on SO to be honest. standard array_merge() creates new keys in the $current array...

Answer (score 1):

PHP will not create arrays in $_GET/$_POST unless you tell it to:

```
Import data: <textarea type="text" name="import[]"></textarea>
                                               ^^---- need these
```

Without the `[]`, PHP will treat any duplicate field names as strings to be overwritten. With `[]` in the name, PHP will treat them as new elements in an array.

Comment: I get that, but it still doesn't work. Looks like I'm getting something like: `array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "array(\'foo\'=>\'bar\');" }` (and after stripping slashes): `array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "'foo' => 'bar'" }`. Is this normal, or WordPress creates this mess? In both cases it doesn't update the original array.

Comment: that is an array. if you mean you're entering pseudo-php into your textrea , literally `foo => bar`, then no, that's not how PHP works. you'd have to parse the input data yourself and convert it to an array.

Comment: Then that's the issue most likely, what am I supposed to do then? Create foreach loop? I'm literally entering `array('foo'=>'bar')` there (it's an import / export feature, export textarea displays all the current keys & values, then I copy it and want to be able to restore them in the future).

Comment: use something like json to encode that array. you do NOT want to be allowing raw php-ish code to be entered like that and get anywhere near a context in which it could be executed. a simple json string is easy to cut 'n paste, and will decode back to a native array without ever becoming "executable".

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$current['import'] = $import;
```

Or you can change your html this way:

```
<textarea type="text" name="myarray['import']"></textarea>
```

And in php:

```
$import = $_POST['myarray'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**The second argument is not an array.**

```
$_POST['import'] = value received from the form.
```

With that said, try:

```
$current [] = $_POST['import'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to get from $_POST['import'] ?

you are using a textarea to get an array?

if it's just a single variable then use array_push

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php

for array_merge you need to have 2 arrays.