# $http POST array params sent incorrectly in payload : Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, payload

i am assigning an array to a key which need to be send in the payload of POST call in my angular js application. for example like below.

```
this.selectedCtlIds =[877, 982, 091, 112];

function saveFormSettings() {
 let data = this.settings; // have various key from the GET call
 data.statusIdToBeChanged = this.selectedCtlIds;
 console.log(data.statusIdToBeChanged, 'test '); // works fine

 Service.updateSettings(data).then(function (resp) {
  //POST CALL HERE
}

}


function updateSettings(param) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + '/setting',
        params: param
    })
}
```

expected payload by api is like `statusIdToBeChanged: [877, 982, 091, 112]`

instead it is passed like below when i checked in network payload

```
statusIdToBeChanged[]: 284
statusIdToBeChanged[]: 982
statusIdToBeChanged[]: 091
statusIdToBeChanged[]: 112
```

due to which the api is failing. i am not sure why it is like this in payload.

Comment: can you post the code of ```Service.updateSettings``` and your ```update call```

Comment: in http post method pass data through body why params ?

Comment: if still you want through params then make it stringfy
params: `\`${param}\``

Comment: This seems like normal syntax to me: [How to pass an array using $\_POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690941/how-to-pass-an-array-using-post). Arrays show up with [] for every value. Or here: [submitting html form values as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909742/submitting-html-form-values-as-array-to-php). If the API expects JSON, convert to JSON string first.